# How can I get single item using id from the container in CosmosDb

Tags: api, express, postman, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

As the title explains, I want to get the item using the id.
Right now I have set up the GET API that returns me all the documents inside the container in Cosmos DB.
Now what I am trying to do is set up the GET API that will use a specific id and returns that Id's document.

This is what I have tried..

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const dbResponse = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({
            id: databaseId
        });
        let database = dbResponse.database;
    
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({id: containerId});

        // const querySpec = {
        //     query: "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = 4040c"
        //   };


        const result = await (database.container.items.id);
        console.log(result);
        
    } catch (error) {
        
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send("Error with database query: " + error.body);
        
    }

})
```

using database.container.items.id gives me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

I am running the GET method in postman with this route: localhost:3000/4040c.
Where 4040c is the actual id of the document stored in the database.

Now I am thinking of using SQL query but I am not sure how to do so or even if it is the right way.
Any tip or guidance is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following if you know both item's id and partition key value:

```
const item = container.item('item-id', 'item-partition-key-value');
const result = await item.read();
const itemDetails = result.resource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the GET method on the docs resource.

```
    https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs/{doc-id}
```

If this is a partitioned container you need to pass the partition key value in the header. You can get the complete syntax and example in the [Data Plane REST API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document)

Comment: Okay trying this now